# LinkedIn Scraper: How do I convert a list of company names into LinkedIn URLs

Tags: python, linkedin-api, scraper

I have a LinkedIn scraper (built in Python) already set up which takes a list of company URLs as input, and outputs all the information about that company (such as location, website, and size (number of employees)).

The problem is the input: it takes a list of URLs but I have a list of company names. Is there a way I can convert a list of company names into a list of LinkedIn URLs to feed into the scraper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following link to make a GET request. Just fill in the placeholder with the company name. It'll return a JSON with the URL. You'll have to parse the JSON to get the URL though.

`http://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query={company}&types=company,group,sitefeature`

Example: If I want to search for google, it'll be `https://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=google&types=company,group,sitefeature`

JSON response will be:

```
{"company":{"resultList":[{"displayName":"Google","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAVrAAAAJDZhMGIyZDk0LWJlMDAtNGM1OS1hNjBmLWNlN2RmMDI4ZWU4MQ.png","subLine":"Internet; 10,001+ employees","id":"1441","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/1441","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong>"},{"displayName":"Google, Social Marketing Tools","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/5/005/0b3/210/3dc667d.png","subLine":"Internet; 10,001+ employees","id":"621453","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/621453","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong>, Social Marketing Tools"},{"displayName":"Google SEO (Page 1 Google)","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/4/000/139/37d/3d91dea.png","subLine":"Internet; 1-10 employees","id":"2486941","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2486941","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> SEO (Page 1 <strong>Google<\/strong>)"},{"displayName":"Google Account Managers","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/7/000/1e3/199/293d5b2.png","subLine":"Marketing and Advertising; 1-10 employees","id":"2871869","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2871869","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Account Managers"},{"displayName":"Google Adsense","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/1/005/096/0c6/37184a2.png","subLine":"Consumer Services; 10,001+ employees","id":"5392727","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/5392727","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Adsense"},{"displayName":"Google / Titan Aerospace","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/6/000/220/1c0/16d865f.png","subLine":"Airlines/Aviation; 11-50 employees","id":"3017073","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/3017073","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> / Titan Aerospace"},{"displayName":"Google AdWords Certified","subLine":"Marketing and Advertising; 1-10 employees","id":"2321528","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2321528","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> AdWords Certified"},{"displayName":"Google Developers Group - Twin Cities [GDG-TC]","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/7/000/20b/0de/07e4bfb.png","subLine":"Computer Software; 51-200 employees","id":"2969362","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2969362","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Developers Group - Twin Cities [GDG-TC]"},{"displayName":"Google Website Analytics Strategies","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/7/005/02b/2d9/1ff2ce7.png","subLine":"Internet; 1-10 employees","id":"3547830","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/3547830","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Website Analytics Strategies"},{"displayName":"Google Apps Authorized Reseller | Bmeet.it","subLine":"Information Technology and Services; 1-10 employees","id":"2336657","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2336657","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Apps Authorized Reseller | Bmeet.it"},{"displayName":"Google Business View: Google går indenfor i din virksomhed","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/2/000/241/1af/2f5a4b8.png","subLine":"Photography; 1-10 employees","id":"3081545","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/3081545","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Business View: <strong>Google<\/strong> g&#xe5;r indenfor i din virksomhed"},{"displayName":"Google Developers Group Karachi","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/5/005/090/3fb/249c792.png","subLine":"Computer Software; 201-500 employees","id":"4792172","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/4792172","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Developers Group Karachi"},{"displayName":"Google Plus Daily","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/6/000/23e/197/1e7f025.png","subLine":"Online Media; 1-10 employees","id":"3075681","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/3075681","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Plus Daily"},{"displayName":"Google Up Me","subLine":"Marketing and Advertising; 1-10 employees","id":"2520581","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2520581","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Up Me"},{"displayName":"Google Maps | Business View - Scotland (Business Photos Tayside)","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/7/000/22a/19f/27daaeb.png","subLine":"Photography; 1-10 employees","id":"3036963","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/3036963","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Maps | Business View - Scotland (Business Photos Tayside)"},{"displayName":"Google Business Photos","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/6/000/1d2/30c/03168cc.png","subLine":"Information Technology and Services; 1-10 employees","id":"2833336","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2833336","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Business Photos"},{"displayName":"Google Business Groups (GBG), Dhaka","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/6/000/20e/028/1c2f5ce.png","subLine":"Internet; 1-10 employees","id":"2975848","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2975848","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Business Groups (GBG), Dhaka"},{"displayName":"Google Trusted Photographer","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/3/000/1fc/397/2bd3aa2.png","subLine":"Photography; 1-10 employees","id":"2933225","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2933225","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Trusted Photographer"},{"displayName":"Google Business Photos Vancouver","subLine":"Marketing and Advertising; 1-10 employees","id":"2847917","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/2847917","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Business Photos Vancouver"},{"displayName":"Google Developers Group Buenos Aires","imageUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/6/005/092/003/1d8e0ca.png","subLine":"Information Technology and Services; 11-50 employees","id":"3572623","url":"http://www.linkedin.com/company/3572623","headLine":"<strong>Google<\/strong> Developers Group Buenos Aires"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search using the Linkedin API for a specific company name, then take the first result and extract the link from the returned search result and use that to gather more information about the company.